# ExtJs ComboBox auto expand

Tags: extjs, combobox

I'm trying to expand contents of combo box after event.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

var mycb = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
   //params
});

//here is other event
var other = ....
  onChange: function() {
    //here I'm trying to expand
    mycb.expand();
}
});
```

But after expand() and putting '*' reqex for search conditions there's no expanding list. I've tried to use 'minChars' param setted to 0, but the there's also no results.

Answer (score 2):

If you want auto expand the list of comboBox, you can use "onTriggerClick()":

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

   var mycb = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
     // params
     listeners: {
        afterrender: function (cb) {
           cb.onTriggerClick();
        }
     }
   });

});
```

This example auto expand contents of your combo box after render...

Answer (score 1):

Try to load combo's store before expanding it.

Answer (score 1):

Call expand() after load().

```
listeners: {
    change: function (obj, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        store.proxy.extraParams.keyword = newValue;
        store.load();
        this.expand();
    }
}  // listeners
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for me on extjs3.3. may it help some one

```
var taxonomyTreePanel = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        id: 'taxTreePanel',
        store:new Ext.data.SimpleStore({fields:[],data:[[]]}),
        editable:false,
        //z-index: 7000,
        typeAhead:false,//done by siddhartha
        selectOnFocus:true, 
        shadow:false,
        mode: 'local',
        triggerAction:'all',
        maxHeight: 200,
        width: 340,
        emptyText:"Select Resource Category",
        tpl: '<tpl for="."><div style="height:210px"><div id="taxonomyTreediv"></div></div></tpl>',
        selectedClass:'',
        forceSelection: true,
        onSelect:Ext.emptyFn,
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (obj) {
               if(singleParamDynamicQuery &&docTypeCodeDynamciQuery.length>0){  
                    obj.onTriggerClick();
               }
            }
        },
        onViewClick : function(doFocus){
         //do nothing
        }
        });
```